# How to fix Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following Typescript function:

```js
const setter = <T = Record<string, string>>(obj: T, prop: keyof T, val: string): void => {
    obj[prop] = val;
};
```

I get the following error from my IDE:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'
```

If T is a Record of string keys and string values and `prop` is a key of T, then I originally assumed that I could assign a string to `T[keyof T]`.

What is the proper use of generics to fix this error?

Comment: `T` can be anything the caller of the function wants; it just *defaults* to `Record<string, string>` if inference fails.  So that code doesn’t mean what you want it to mean.

Comment: Note that your title is “how to fix” but your question text is “why is this broken”.  Those are different.  Which one do you really want answered?  If it's "how to fix" then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3ydjw) meet your needs?

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: @jcalz your solution works. please post as an answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The immediate problem with

```
const setter = <T = Record<string, string>>(
  obj: T, prop: keyof T, val: string
): void => {
  obj[prop] = val; // error! 'string' is not assignable to 'T[keyof T]'
};
```

is that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` can be absolutely anything the *caller* of the function wants it to be.  All you've done with `T = Record<string, string>` is specified that `T` would [*default*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `Record<string, string>` in the (unlikely) event that the compiler could not infer anything for `T`.  But `T` will be inferred by whatever value is passed in as `obj`, if not specified manually by the caller:

```
setter({ a: 1 }, "a", "oops"); // no compiler error
```

So this isn't what you wanted to say.

---

Perhaps you were trying to [*constrain*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to `Record<string, string>` instead of defaulting to it.  That is denoted with `extends`, not `=`:

```
const setter = <T extends Record<string, string>>(
  obj: T, prop: keyof T, val: string
): void => {
  obj[prop] = val; // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'
};
```

That would at least prevent people from making completely incorrect calls where `obj` has a non-`string` property at the relevant key::

```
setter({ a: 1 }, "a", "oops"); // error!
// ----> ~ // number is not assignable to string
```

But the problem with constraints like this is that the caller could *narrow* properties to something more specific than `string`, such as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
type Foo = { b: "x" | "y" };
const foo: Foo = { b: "x" };
badSetter2(foo, "b", "oopsie"); // no compiler error
```

Here, `foo` is of type `Foo`, an object type whose `b` property must either be `"x"` or `"y"`.  And we've apparently assigned `"oopsie"` to its `b` property, which shouldn't be allowed.

This kind of narrowing might be unlikely for your expected use cases, but the compiler is concerned about it, so the error remains.  You can't necessarily assign `string` to `obj[prop]`.

---

One way to fix this is to make sure that `val` is of a type that can be assigned to the specific key at `prop`.  That involves adding a type parameter for the key:

```
const setter = <T extends Record<string, string>, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T, prop: K, val: T[K]
): void => {
  obj[prop] = val; // okay
};

setter({ a: 1 }, "a", "oops"); // compiler error
setter(foo, "b", "oopsie"); // compiler error
setter({ z: "hello" }, "z", "goodbye"); // okay
```

Now everything works as desired.  With `prop` as type `K`, and `val` as type `T[K]` (the type you get when you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) an object of type `T` with a key of type `K`), then `val` can be seen as assignable to `obj[prop]`.  And the invalid calls to `setter()` from above are rightly rejected.

That's probably the "right" way to do this.

---

You can simplify it a bit (at the expense of a little correctness) by removing `T` entirely.  All you care about is that `obj` has a `string` valued key at the `prop` property, then you can leave `K` and rephrase like this:

```
const setter = <K extends PropertyKey>(
  obj: Record<K, string>, prop: K, val: string
): void => {
  obj[prop] = val; // okay
};

setter({ a: 1 }, "a", "oops"); // compiler error
setter(foo, "b", "oopsie"); // okay?!
setter({ z: "hello" }, "z", "goodbye"); // okay
```

This again prevents crazy calls, but still allows erroneous calls like setting `foo.b` to `"oopsie"`.

---

And finally, you could simplify this even further; if you don't even care about the particular key type `K`, you can just make this a non-generic function:

```
const setter = (
  obj: Record<string, string>, prop: string, val: string
): void => {
  obj[prop] = val;
};

setter({ a: 1 }, "a", "oops"); // compiler error
setter(foo, "b", "oopsie"); // okay?!
setter({ z: "hello" }, "z", "goodbye"); // okay
```

This is not worse than the previous one in terms of false negatives, but might have more false positives, which I won't get into because this answer is too long already.

---

So there you go.  You have a spectrum of solutions to choose from ranging from fully generic to fully non-generic, any of which may be more or less useful depending on your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.6.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwCYGUCmUpoE4wLwwA8AKvjAEpqjZKHTYCWYA5gDQz1PMB83AFAFgAUDBgg4AKwBcMYuwAO2EPJkBrNAE8QAM1nsAbggA2Mzi2EBKGfpAMk+bjADew0eIkBtRcoC6ZQ0YA3DAA9CGyGvJoMADkZswxMAwQMGAgsAgQEAzMYAhwRtFQIDBQkdExxB7qWrrEPjEAdHwATADMLS0WwgC+gcLCiKgYWNh8TjAIMgCMMD3sAEQIC4sgyhALFsFhqSWgALbyDIW4OErYA0KgkLBD6Jg4LWQkMGgAHlhgSCmU1LTx7HivEEIjEkhkchg3hUMBqOj0MACpigjHMQisiNs9jwjhcoPcXiU8j8BAC23CxHKsXiiWSuwyWRyeQKRRKZSisSqcLqDV6-SEg2Q91GLXGkxmc0Wy1W6025Ne2HOAEJhDsALQazUaxwAP1C4TAAFd9nAcEkUmkGdlcvlCqUSvFLuzogAxNZkCZwGQLN4LGAAHxgCw0fr6wmu0Bg2jWMjdJQInu9vrm-LuI0efGjIEWcBWQbW8myaDl+t2MAORxOCvOl0uEdu6ewwrNBBe70+3woVBANDoKK4gP7LG47AA0q8PmgvilubJ+K4wdIEdCZKODMYIR5Rz5LNYsQ5nAuCdCSYjjPKQKoEBo+ZdTQ8m42xVMYLN5kHpfnZVtSxXjmazh7QZG2bMYsxzPMFgLIsSx2P8q0Ai4hHvUZQLFAAvb0AAs0CMIwQFDRZ0Mg5g1iQOANGLH8dkva9awFK5wEjCBG2ecd2ynTsAAUiRwMpR00ed8XBLs-kINcOCHHgFCJVd1xMSTUWYXdMTsA88TcSRCV8fxz1vBiWIfZ8JXfJZIOg2DwnggDFSAoRDNGTM1ggmVCwYKiLyvDQAH4VXsp8JkwoMcLwgjJSDYjFlIkByMoyyxC8+j6w4RsXSYYwyBBTSl1+Ht-ikwclJHKFZMUgczwUx10T3NScUPYTPBPXSgn04QHJwNK8iMYzX3CszXI2airJAQ5-1OWykPa7BOuMJzsyDXMBvc+LaJ8vyppm7rAuw3D8MIiKSLIiiPNLVb6OEIA)

Comment: I have read _quite a number_ of your answers to similar questions, but based on how great this one I think this should from now on be used as a possible duplicate for everything else.

Comment: I agree 100% with zerkms. I found many answers did partly addressed my issue. Now I'm just waiting for @jcalz to publish his book on Typescript