# React + Typescript: Problem with React.Key when item[keyProp]

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to make a general component that render a list. I am having trouble when i have to pass the key. I thought I was passing the property name which is to be taken as a key, but I get an error

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"

interface HorizontalSectionProps<T> {
  // Title of the section
  title: string
  // Items that render each element of the section
  card: (args0: T) => React.ReactNode
  // Items to show
  items: T[]
  // Property that is a key
  keyProp: keyof T

  // Loading state
  isLoading?: boolean
}

/**
 * This component is used to display a horizontal section with a title and a list of items
 * For mobile there is an horizontal scrolling section
 * For tablet  there is grids of cards displayed in max 2 rows
 * For desktop there is grids of cards displayed in one 1 row
 * @param {HorizontalSectionProps} props
 */
export default function HorizontalSection<T>({
  title,
  card,
  items,
  keyProp,
  isLoading = false,
}: HorizontalSectionProps<T>) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="text-2xl sm:text-3xl mb-6">{title}</h2>

      {isLoading ? (
        <>Loading</>
      ) : (
        <>
          {/* ===== MOBILE HORIZONTAL SECTION ===== */}
          <Swiper
            slidesPerView={2}
            // centeredSlides={true}
            spaceBetween={10}
            loop={true}
            grabCursor={true}
            pagination={{
              clickable: true,
              type: "bullets",
            }}
            className="mySwiper card-swiper sm:hidden"
          >
            {items?.map((item, index) => (
                //TODO: Here I have the error on key property
              <SwiperSlide key={item[keyProp]}>{card(item)}</SwiperSlide>
            ))}
          </Swiper>

          {/* ===== DESKTOP HORIZONTAL SECTION ===== */}
          <div className="hidden sm:grid grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-5 gap-x-4 gap-y-10 sm:gap-y-6 mb-10">
            {items?.map((item) => card(item))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'Key | null | undefined'.
  Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'Key | null | undefined'.
    Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'Key | null | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

EDIT: I added the way i use the component, so you can understand better. Inside card i pass the component that needs to be rendered for each item and inside keyProp I wanted to pass the name of the property that acts as a key

```
        <div className="recSection my-12 app-max-width app-x-padding">
          <HorizontalSection<Product>
            title={t("you_may_also_like")}
            card={(item: Product) => <Card key={item.nodo} item={item} />}
            items={suggestedProducts}
            keyProp="nodo"
          />
        </div>
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72021963/how-to-fix-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-tkeyof-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the cases like this, you need to have an abstraction based on your key:

```js
interface HorizontalSectionProps<K extends string, T extends Record<K, string | number>> {
  // Title of the section
  title: string;
  // Items that render each element of the section
  card: (args0: T) => ReactNode;
  // Items to show
  items: T[];
  // Property that is a key
  // old answer: keyProp: keyof T;
  keyProp: K;

  // Loading state
  isLoading?: boolean;
}
```

Then you'll need to change your component to look like this:

```js
export default function HorizontalSection<K extends string, T extends Record<K, string | number>>({
  title,
  card,
  items,
  keyProp,
  isLoading = false,
}: HorizontalSectionProps<K, T>) {
```

Then it'll assume that `T[K]` is a string or a number.

See the example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktgGbQDuKUJyFcAvnBVBCHAORQEzcA3AChhaCADsAzvADK1YGCRRZAG2Bk4AXjY06DJBQAURsBzBSAXHBQSAntj4UAlNoB8cI8Lg%204AHhJgADdcADpwswgLVgB6N2FnZxFxaTkFJShtXShaekYTSItrWwc4J1ctDy9ff0CQnHDQwqlY%20MSRYWAJGGUKdCQ4AAloYAAvSRgUVVkkDGBJAAVzKT8AaTgkAA8eiRIpOBkoLoBzbAAVDe2kXf3kcXo17EOTuAAfOAkAVxAAI2U3Dw4bxwGIxOBnYAwVQDCBMGAACwGUlmMHmEmBqKhSGszwkx2BoLgAEkeiB9giUPA%20LtlBt0PCNtCQNd4LC4AikSi0cC0PprEY6McpAAGaxnCoeZDoGDEMgEsEkpBk9kQA7wiDUYGQpVWcEAbQAuvK4EsosoYHZ2fDKXBgPsUHAANZIOzA512U1gazutlnUQ%20QkAGQgKECeIOkx6WqkwdDJwA-NYfhAINDbMJmKIYgAqbPebPg%20F2uDicCSFm2-afZEkFVwQJSMCqFCWh3qo7jbpTA5cyRwBQImzsyHQmy7IfqGRwNnasn5uAAMWgcBAEB%20wFHHL4lbHcHbYwm3akaA4qnU4eRc0k86XmUmP2h8CtygGxeORz206YvPo%20wbTZbJBay6FcUE2OAACYyg1KQb2XMgpEdGAomfbc3w-fY2R-T9-2bOwgNtCRpwkAYAEZoM1OACwAATAOgUC4HBhg7Q9pl7CRPRaOBmnzGJhC2SBYHrQwUE%20VR4AoT4JCvIjmIPLs2JktZLh2T9cVOcEVOuT87mgEhHgjI5w3eL5fn%20NwjCBHxMWhTAeX0OyfFnKRHKdF1PVcu1YzDY4sj6VRkTs5hrDkztJkU1FFmWAyzjcVwrLKJAYE%20KAiOqXw-HiGofD8eEoLQZspCkQgGKQLQACIem2ABaCDNlUA4QEsKqYGqgBmeqVx%20aqADZyrcHAbKQZg-BiPL4mBGocC8kMfLgeNPEm7LMu8k5Rqy7LXH5JaakynbspwHNtC0E6dAAWQAeQAISJQMAFEhguhAiQALQuwgzgAQUDOBZDugBhM4iXe47TqomJM2y5b5EUZR9qhqR1AQhZlAANWAJBqC0HAIMhqHssJNAWRfEg1A0JApGxmAoE%20Yb4eyxt%20iupLqCQa5sdI4U8fx3xVBTMAqZpumeZqd8UB%20f6UqkaBBdp7mRbo44ukpNFsYSkXfAK4A0EdcXoWsanadcjXrLsJRrHKn4xMfKRyuNkXmHlnmCpQIqSuZCqQDsGGMhLfRqqkdJaSkJqixIMgJHK%20mfA2jXptJKR41CEAUDAExZ2wLoyE2CVFpNgmYjOC6ABELpCl9iT3FAggGDkNigDhMj7d1uPMc1XXznKfeUMnNHdbHZz1d1PQNZgBuwoxZ2cEaYm7lQkaQWORcSJ3ltnoOoAmuOjtOk64GLu7ZFWIuFke563o%2077foBoGQd3nRswh6PamCEtCuK0qKrDiPGssd8NDgP-Eg1VxABVqr-IBIDUxSHaiuEgf8PxQLAQAVkAanaqmxqoABY0FgGqnYaqnMIHoIIT1LqhDhT9Wfj4eOOok4pzTpPUkucJ5T2ns-UadQl67TiPtdhPCNrOAzEAA).

## Updates:

You can just change the `keyProp` to have type `K` in the type of props and it'll guess some types for you. See the updated example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktgGbQDuKUJyFcAvnBVBCHAORQEzcA3AChhaCADsAzvADK1YGCRRZAG2Bk4AXjY06DJBQAURsBzBSAXHBQSAntj4UAlNoB8cI8Lg%204AHhJgADdcADpwswgLVgB6N2FnZxFxaTkFJShtXShaekYTSItrWwc4J1ctDy9ff0CQnHDQwqlY%20MSRYWAJGGUKdCQ4AAUOEgBXDFxvOAlSJGsZKC6AcxEfDXmYRYkV4WZRLp6oPrQBgAloYAAvSRgUVVkkDGBJYaipPwBpOCQADx6JEhSOALZbYAAq3z%20SABQOQ4non2wIO2cAAPtNRiAAEbKNweHBTGIxOBg4AwVQDCBMGAACwGUkeMGeEimTPJc2Bm2WhOJAEkeiAgbSUPA%20ADlN90DTvhSQND4FS4LT6YzmVM0PprEY6EspAAGaxgioeZDoGDEMg8uD8pCCpUQYE0iDUKZk21WEkAbQAulbXhkYHYlTSRXBgECUHAANZIOxTGN2f3WD6iHxEuAAGQgKECKJkIqQrqkWZzywA-NYsRAIBTbLtRDEAFSN7yNkk08NwcTgSTysNA0YMkj2uCBKRgVQoIORp2La7dO7A1WSOAKWk2JVkik2AEb9QyOCKt2C1twABi0DgIAgWOA2%20VfH7O7gs6uN0XUjQHFU6jzy5ZcBthemS3FiFLwMGygDJ2SyLICh5MBq9BAmOE5Tkgw5dFeKA-HAABMZTOlIp7AaOSBSFGMBRJBj4wXBQKKkh8GoZOdgYWGEiHhIAwAIyES6gFwAAAmAdAoFwODnHO773P%20-otHAzStjEwi-JAsBkX0oyqPAFCjBITwrlJb4LrJhkSJ8kL-PByJLOCVnQvBcLQCQiKclsSxohi2K4m4RgEj4bIUpg6r6CFawClI4XRrG-rReGJa5p5Oh9KoDIhcw1jGfOtxmUyLzmO8Hzgm4rgBWUSAwKMUCcdUvh%20PENQ%20H4NIEWgk5SFIhDiUgWgAEQ9H8AC0eE-KowIgJYg0wENADMY1XliQ0AGx9W4OBBUgzB%20DErXxFMNQ4Al2ZJXAZaeAdTUNYlyw7Y1TWuFql01A1z1NTgTbaFo306AAsgA8gAQryGYAKJwKc-0ILyABa-2EGCACCGZwLIoMAMJgry8NfT9gExHsTVXfIijKG9RNSOoZBSIMygAGrAEg1BaDgeGE0TTXpic3RQSQagaORLObKMW3k01479IDlXUEg0IszxersxzviqNWYBC1AItK8rcCwSgWLo9VUjQBrWtizUolLF0IrMiz5U6747XAGgUb6xS1jC%20Q5tNYGSjWH1WLaeBUh9dFDvMNryvtSgnXdXK-UgHYJMZF2%20hDVI6QSlIk0diQZASH13v3Q7R2RWWoQgCgYAmMe2BdGQPzGhdDtE0SYL-QAIv9WVQdaL4oEEAzKt8UAcJkK4Jop5jKIG3svcnyj85oCYs8enoJv63rMOtTFGMezjbTEC8qFTSDFzriSR1dR%20Z1A%200l59P3fXAHeg7IHzt4MENQ7D8NIyjaNMbY0ILjZ%20jYCbewCMELsHUuo9X6rnfOE1LCwQ0LrOCQ1xBpRGsg1BJBME1ikHNK8JAUEYKwUQgArLrKuQ0fhDQACw0LAENOwQ0Fa4NoWw5ai12F6jWnPXAx4pDl0rtXPeAom6733gfSBMQ6jnxenEN6silH3WcPWMQkgDzCOsK8MYGAfRZB9B0dMMxqA2CBHYCAoxFIxyBMIkcOIhgjHGDAIxypOJkjgAAK0HPAJYItOrkRsD%20Q8D4lR2CUECLEMd2IrmHhvcwO5hz6LcSkuA1jbEkEkNweAIZB4jlEp1SCIBhDpiyanTidxjZ2JKcqLgwAmCVNoN0LRqQlzmSyHVPw2UZIPHMpdTaLNuCyE4AMUk7JuDayYizUwriMBNygUEdakQDEwFCBoQ%20CjtbCNXpFbWSSogjJmGQaZhI2hAA).

Comment: Thank a lot, now works. The only doubt I have is that now I have a repetition when I call the component ( I repeat the key "node" two times).
```
<HorizontalSection<"node", Product>
            title={t("you_may_also_like")}
            card={(item: Product) => <Card key={item.nodo} item={item} />}
            items={suggestedProducts}
            keyProp="node"
          />
```

Comment: Hey @Marco, I've updated the answer and added a new example, adding the fix and showing how you can use it not to have many repeats.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You didn't include the example props, but let say that `T` is a `string`

Now `keyof T` is something like: `keyProp: number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | ... 30 more ... | "padEnd"`

### Solution

You probably meant:

```
keyof T[];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited and included the example props. I don't think this is the right answer because inside keyProp there is the name of one property of the object that can be used as React.Key