# Mapped type functions getter

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have these types:

```
type Device = {
  manufacturer: string;
  price: number;
  releaseYear: number;
};

type Accessory = {
  color: string;
  size: number;
};
```

And I have formatter:

```
type Formatter<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T as `format${Capitalize<Key & string>}`]: (
    value: T[Key]
  ) => string;
};
```

I want to create a function which returns formatted type by generic. Something like this:

```
const getFormatted = <T>(obj: T): Formatter<T> {
  const newObj: Formatter<T> = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      newObj[`format${capitalize(key)}`] = () => obj[key];
  })

  return newObj;
}

const { formatColor, formatSize } = getFormatted<Accessory>({
  color: "#fff",
  size: 2
})
```

But I got errors:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`format${string}`' can't be used to index type 'Formatter '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript does not know if the key of newObj is a valid key of the Formatter type. This is because TypeScript cannot infer the exact keys created by the template literal in [Key in keyof T as format${Capitalize<Key & string>}].

To fix this issue, you can add a type assertion on the key when adding it to newObj, which tells TypeScript that the dynamic key you are using matches the type of keys defined in Formatter

```
type Device = {
  manufacturer: string;
  price: number;
  releaseYear: number;
};

type Accessory = {
  color: string;
  size: number;
};

type Formatter<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T as `format${Capitalize<Extract<Key, string>>}`]: (
    value: T[Extract<Key, keyof T>]
  ) => string;
};

interface MyObject {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean;
}

function getFormatted<T extends MyObject>(obj: T): Formatter<T> {
  const newObj: Formatter<T> = {} as Formatter<T>;
  
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const formattedKey = `format${capitalize(key)}` as keyof Formatter<T>;
        newObj[formattedKey] = (value: T[keyof T]): string => `${value}`;
  });

  return newObj;
}

const { formatColor, formatSize } = getFormatted<Accessory>({
  color: "#fff",
  size: 2
})

function capitalize(str: string): string {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: After I get this error "Type '(value: T[keyof T]) => string' is not assignable to type 'Formatter [keyof Formatter ]'." on  newObj[formattedKey]

Comment: sorry i forgot add :string on the newObj[formattedKey] , can you try again like i edited ?

Comment: No. I got same error

Comment: It seems like the error is related to the generic type T not being constrained to a specific type or interface, so this time it might be

Comment: The same error. I found this issue, but can't solve my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72021963/how-to-fix-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-tkeyof-t

Comment: i think the issues happen due to type formatter , i gave full code so that you won't get me wrong..

Comment: I still got that error, but I suppress it with @ts-ignore. Other functionality is working. Thanks a lot